# on projection maps and inverse images

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have sets $X_1,X_2,.... $ and we know $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i= \{ (x_1,x_2,....) : x_i \in X_i \} $. Define the map $f: X \to X_i $ by $f( (x_1,x_2,...,x_i,...) ) = x_i $. Why is it true that

$$ f^{-1}_i(E_i) = \{ (x_1,x_2,....) : x_i \in E_i, \; \; and \; \; x_j \in X_j \; \; for \; \; \; i \neq j \} $$

where $E_i = X_i $ when $j \neq i $. Why do we need this condition? I am very confused as to why the preimage is such.

Comment: $E_i$ is any subset of $X_i$?

Comment: Yes, actually to be more precise, Given that $\mathcal{M}_i $ is a $\sigma-$algebra on $X_i $ for all $i$, we have that $E_i \in \mathcal{M}_i $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the **definition** of [pre-image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image). If $f_i: \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n \to X_i$ is given by $f_i((x_n)_{n \geq 1}) = x_i$, and if $E_i \subset X_i$ is given, then: $$f_i^{-1}(E_i) = \left\{ (x_n)_{n \geq 1} \in \prod_{n \geq 1}X_n \mid f_i((x_n)_{n \geq 1}) \in E_i   \right\} = \left\{ (x_n)_{n \geq 1} \in \prod_{n \geq 1}X_n \mid x_i \in E_i   \right\}.$$

Your condition "and $x_j \in X_j$ for $i \neq j$" is trivial and always holds. Maybe that's what confused you.

Comment: Why then $E_i = X_i $ when $j \neq i $. I don't understand this part.

Comment: This part is actually superflous.. that is badly written. It does not makes any sense talking about "$E_i  = X_i$ when $j \neq i$". It would be more reasonable to say "$E_j = X_j$ when $j \neq i$", but then again, what are the $E_j$? They aren't even defined.

Comment: is in the comment below my question

Comment: The point is that *only* the $i$-th entry of the sequence $(x_1,x_2, \cdots)$ must be in $E_i$. The other entries can be anywhere. More exactly: $$f_i^{-1}(E_i) = \left\{ (x_n)_{n \geq 1} \in \prod_{n \geq 1}X_n \mid f_i((x_n)_{n \geq 1}) \in E_i   \right\}$$ and **not** $$f_i^{-1}(E_i) = \left\{ (x_n)_{n \geq 1} \in \prod_{n \geq 1}E_n \mid f_i((x_n)_{n \geq 1}) \in E_i   \right\},$$unless you put that condition.

Comment: But, then I don't understand why my book claims that 

$$ f_i^{-1}(E_i) = \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} E_j $$

where $E_j = X_j $ for $j \neq i $.

Comment: Now this is correct. Better to write " $\prod_{j=1}^\infty E_j$ where $E_j  = X_j$ for $j \neq i$" than to write: $$X_1 \times X_2 \times \cdots \times X_{i-1}\times E_i \times X_{i+1}\times \cdots.$$It is just to simplify the writing.

Comment: Re-read carefully our above discussion. This set really is $f_i^{-1}(E_i)$.

Comment: Ok, so to see if I have understood, Lets use play with two sets, say $X_1,X_2$ and $E_1,E_2 $. Then, I know 

$$ E_1 \times E_2 = \{ (x_1,x_2) : x_i \in E_i \} $$

and 

$$ f_1^{-1}(E_1) = \{ (x_1,x_2) : x_1 \in E_1 , \; \; x_2 \in X_2 \} $$

Hence, since $X_2$ can be any set, I can make $X_2 = E_2$ and it matches my first set. correct?

Comment: Yesssssssssssss! (enough s' to make the minimum number of characters haha)

Comment: @user222186 It is correct, but $f_{1}^{-1}[E_1] = \{(x_1, x_2) \in X_1 \times X_2 ~|~ x_1 \in E_1\}$ is what Terek actually wrote in the answer;  it's a matter of convenience. (Though the user retired.)

Answer (score 2):

$\pi_i^{-1}(E_i)$ contains all elements that project down to $E_i$, so you can say that $\pi^{-1}(E_i)= X_1 \times X_2 \times...X_{i-1} \times E_i \times X_{i+1} \times....$. Any term in the product space that is in $E_i$, will project down
to $E_i$ . For an element  $(x_1,x_2,...)$ in $\Pi_{i=1}^{\infty}$ to project down to $E_i$, its $i_{th}$ coordinate must be in $E_i$.

Take a small example of the interval $(2,3)$ in the $x$-axis within the $x-y$-plane. Can you see its preimage under $\pi_2$? It is $\mathbb R \times ( 2,3)$, since every point $(x,y)$ , with $2<x<3$ will project down to $(2,3)$ under $\pi_2$. So $\pi_2^{-1}(E_i)$ consists of all sequences ( since your indexing set is the Natural numbers here) , whose i-th coordinate contains points in $E_i$. Still, note that you can do a product over any index, not just the Natural numbers.